# Include 2nd variable labels on an existing Variable vs sample plot geom_jitter

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `geom_jitter` plot showing Variables between 2 samples, I would like to include the Group-variable parameters on the left of the plot, setting a separation by lines like in the figure below. Thus, Variables are organised by Group.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
data<- tibble::tibble(
  Variable = c("A","B","C","D","E", "F"),
  Group = c("Asia","Asia","Europe","Europe","Africa","America"),
  sample1 = c(0.38,0.22,0.18,0.12,0.1,0),
  sample2 = c(0.23,0.2,0,0.12,0.11,0.15))


library(reshape2)
data2<- melt(data,
        id.vars=c("Variable", "Group"),
        measure.vars=c("sample1", "sample2"),
        variable.name="Sample",
        value.name="value")

data22[is.na(data22)] <- 0
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data2, aes(x = Sample, y = Variable, label=NA)) +
    geom_point(aes(size = value, colour = value)) + 
    geom_text(hjust = 1, size = 2) +
    # scale_size(range = c(1,3)) +
    theme_bw()+
  scale_color_gradient(low = "lightblue", high = "darkblue")
```

Here is the current output I have:
[image: Current output:]

And this is the format I would like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a polished version of the plot most similar to your ideal plot, you can use `facet_grid()` plus some `theme()` customization.

```
ggplot(data2, aes(x = Sample, y = Variable, label=NA)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = value, colour = value)) + 
  geom_text(hjust = 1, size = 2) +
  # scale_size(range = c(1,3)) +
  theme_bw()+
  scale_color_gradient(low = "lightblue", high = "darkblue") +
  facet_grid(Group~., scales = "free", switch = "y") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 180),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "cm"))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thanks :)  and if I want to choose a specific order of the Group variable? where in the code can I add it? Let's say order Europe, America, Africa, Asia

Comment: Make that a `?factor()` and set the levels to the order you want.